# ¿Cómo eliminar imagen y vista previa de múltiples imágenes con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

me encontré con una pregunta relacionada a lo que estoy haciendo que es la vista previa de múltiples imágenes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn_add').click(function(){
   $('#modal').html('<label>Selecciona las imagenes</label><br><input type="file" id="fl_img" name="fl_img" multiple><div id="resto_form"></div>');
  });
  $(document).on('change','#fl_img',function(e){
    var input =document.getElementById('fl_img');
    var cantidad =input.files.length;
//con esto valido que no tenga una extension aparte de jpg y png
    for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) 
        {
            var nombre = input.files[i].name;
            var ext = nombre.substring(nombre.lastIndexOf("."));
            if (ext != ".png" && ext != ".jpg")
            {
                var valida = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                var valida = true;
            }
        }
//aqui se checa que todos tengan una extension valida
    if (valida) 
        {
    //limpio el area del form
      $('#forms_img').html('');
      //genero el campo del nombre y los separo por un id con el numero de imagen
            for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) 
            {
                $('#resto_form').append('<div id="img'+i+'">    <h3>Imagen Cargada '+(i+1)+'</h3>   <label>Nombre:</label>  <input type="text" id="txt_nombre_img'+i+'" name="txt_nombre_img'+i+'" maxlength="30"></div><br><br>');
        //con esta funcion deberia encargarse de la pre vista
                previsualizarImg(e, i);
                  
            }
        }
        else
        {
    //en caso de que no sean validos las extensiones manda alert y limpio el file
      alert('este archivo no es valido o no se ha seleccionado archvio');
            $('#fl_img').val('');
        }
  });
});
//esta es la funcion previsualizacion
function previsualizarImg(e,i)
{
      var file = e.target.files[i];
    
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e){
            var result = e.target.result;
        $('#img'+i).append(`<img src="${result}" width="450" height="300">`); //Asignamos el src dinámicamente a un img dinámico también
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);     
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Presiona para agregar:</label>
<input type="button" id="btn_add" value="ADD">
<!--lo pongo asi para simular el modal y el agregar los elementos dinamincamente-->
<div id="modal">

</div>
```

Pero también ocupo el poder eliminar la imagen y su previsualización, esto en caso de equivocarme al elegir la imagen, ¿ como podría lograr esto con JavaScript ?

Este código me permite previsualizar la imagen pero en caso de dar clik dos veces para agregar mas imágenes se sobrescriben:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo aquí aparece dos veces imagen 1, cuando se debería reemplazar por la nueva opcion seleccionada, aparte de poder eliminarlas, les agradecería sus ideas para poder resolverlo gracias

Comment: y si pones ` $('#img'+i).empty()` antes del ` $('#img'+i).append(......`

Comment: Hola, gracias, si en efecto puse  $('#prueba').empty(); antes del for y ya no se sobrescriben :), ya solo me falta poder eliminarlas de la fila.

Comment: Buen día Andrea, has podido poner la opción de eliminar cada vista previa previa?, si es asi lo podrás compartir? Gracias

Comment: Hola Jorge, al final no puse opción para eliminarlas, no fue requerido, ya que al poner $('#prueba').empty(); antes del for se eliminan las imágenes que estaban y se remplazan por las nuevas. Saludos.